# label in python docstring

Tags: python-sphinx, mathjax, autodoc, numpydoc

I'm using sphinx autodoc to translate my docstring to a nice documentation page. In the docstring I'm following numpy's docstring guideline by using the sphinx napoleon extension. I'm wondering about the following: If I have an equation like

```
"""
This is a very important equation which is used in the code

.. math::

     a+b=c
   :label: important_eq
"""
```

the autodoc doesn't recognize the `:label:`. Do I have a wrong formatting or can't autodoc / mathjax / napoleon deal with labels in equations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful with whitespace and indentation. This works:

```
.. math::
   :label: important_eq

   a+b=c
```

This works too (when the math content is only one line of text, it can be given as a directive argument):

```
.. math:: a+b=c
   :label: important_eq
```